# Retrieve dimensions of scaled image within SVG

Tags: javascript, asp.net, svg

I am loading different sized images into a content area and, as they are resized proportionally, there is often a gap between any given two sides of the image and the border of the content area.

I layer a rectangle of the top of this image, which opacity is adjusted, to change how visible the background image underneath is. I want this filter to match the size of the image.

This is how the elements are defined:

```
 <td id="svgContentCell">
           <svg id="svg" width="1000" height="750" version="1.1" onload="Init()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            onmousedown="onMouseDown(evt)" onmousemove="onMouseMove(evt)" onmouseup="onMouseUp(evt)" >

            <image id="background" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href=""></image>
            <rect id="filter" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="0"></rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
```

I thought this would be relatively straightforward with Javascript, however I am not able to retrieve any useful data on the size of the `background` image. The client width properties return 0.

```
var bg = document.getElementById('background');
var scrollWidth = bg.scrollWidth; // result: 0
var clientWidth = bg.clientWidth; // result: 0
var offsetWidth = bg.offsetWidth; // result: 0
var width = bg.getAttribute("width"); // result: 100%

// edit: BoundingClientRect() returns size of container not the scaled image.
var bg = document.getElementById("background");
var rect = bg.getBoundingClientRect();
var height = rect.height; // result: 750
var width = rect.width; // result: 1000

// I can retrieve the **unscaled** image dimensions like this
var bg = document.getElementById('background');
var address = bg.getAttribute('xlink:href');
var original = new Image();
original.src = address;
var unscaledWidth = original.width;
var unscaledHeight = original.height;
```

**Does anyone know of a way I can get the actual pixel width and height of the scaled `background` image so I can resize the `filter` element appropriately?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert Longson, who seems like a reliable source, indicated there was no way to retrieve this I wrote my own function to calculate it.

```
function calculateScaledImage() {
    // Get the container dimensions
    var bg = document.getElementById("background");
    var rect = bg.getBoundingClientRect();
    var cHeight = rect.height; // result: 750
    var cWidth = rect.width; // result: 1000

    // Get the unscaled dimensions
    var address = bg.getAttribute('xlink:href');
    // Create new image with URL to get unscaled dimension (not displayed)
    var original = new Image();
    original.src = address;
    var oWidth = original.width;
    var oHeight = original.height;

    // New dimensions and ratio for scaling
    var nWidth;
    var nHeight;
    var ratio;

    var isWide = false;

    // Is the empty space going to be on sides or top
    if (oWidth > oHeight) {
        isWide = true;

            // I found that if the height exceeded the container it scaled it  differently
        if (oHeight > cHeight)
        {
            isWide = false;
        }
    }

    var filter = document.getElementById('filter');
    if (isWide) {
        ratio = cWidth / oWidth;
        nWidth = oWidth * ratio;
        nHeight = oHeight * ratio;

        var adjustment = (cHeight - nHeight) / 2;

        filter.setAttribute("y", adjustment);
        filter.setAttribute("x", 0);
        filter.setAttribute("width", nWidth);
        filter.setAttribute("height", nHeight);
    }
    else {
        ratio = cHeight / oHeight;
        nHeight = oHeight * ratio;
        nWidth = oWidth * ratio;

        var adjustment = (cWidth - nWidth) / 2;

        filter.setAttribute("x", adjustment);
        filter.setAttribute("y", 0);
        filter.setAttribute("width", nWidth);
        filter.setAttribute("height", nHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) should do what you want e.g.

```
var rect = bg.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Then you can pick out the width and height properties from that object.

Comment: I've just tested this out and its returning the dimensions of the SVG container, rather than the values of the scaled image contained within.
`var bg = document.getElementById("background");`
`var rect = bg.getBoundingClientRect();`
`var height = rect.height; // = 750`
`var width = rect.width; // = 1000`

Comment: But the image in your example **is** the size of the container, it's height/width 100% which means size me the size of the container.

Comment: I've added an image to my question to illustrate the issue further. Are you saying that the blank space between the container (green border) and the white background of the image is actually part of the image but made transparent?

Comment: So is that an SVG image as the content? If so what's the outer <svg> element look like? Does it have viewBox or preserveAspectRatio attributes? What's giving the image a white background?

Comment: The `background` image, with the white BG, is a JPG being loaded in like this via a webmethod `document.getElementById('background').setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", pathToImage);`
The SVG has the green circular printer icons drawn onto it, all of it's elements are in my question.

Comment: What you want is not possible then, unless you calculate it yourself. You know the real image dimensions (which you'd have to hardcode) so if the aspectRatio of that differs from the aspectRatio of the container there will be blank space either on the left/right or top/bottom.

Comment: Okay, thanks Robert I will look into calculating it myself. I can actually retrieve the real image dimensions without hardcoding them (if you are interested I just added the code to my question).

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```
var height = document.getElementById('myimage').offsetHeight;
var width = document.getElementById('myimage').offsetWidth;
```

Comment: If you read the question user wants to know the actual pixel width and height of the scaled background image. Nothing to do with offsets